# How can I organize/create an archive listing by Year and month

Tags: archives

I thought this would be simpler using the basic widgets that WP provides but its not.

I need to create

- 2012

  - Decemeber
  - November
  - ...
- 2011

  - December
  - ...

The month items would be links to that archive.

Is this possible?  I would prefer not to use a plugin but if thats the answer its ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function archive_links_custom() {
    global $wpdb, $wp_locale;
    $query = "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS `year`, MONTH(post_date) AS `month`, count(ID) as posts FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY YEAR(post_date), MONTH(post_date) ORDER BY post_date DESC";
    $arcresults = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    if ( $arcresults ) {
        $year = null;
        foreach ( (array) $arcresults as $arcresult ) {
            if($arcresult->year != $year) {
                echo $arcresult->year;
                $year = $arcresult->year;
            }
            $url = get_month_link( $arcresult->year, $arcresult->month );
            $text = sprintf(__('%1$s %2$d'), $wp_locale->get_month($arcresult->month), $arcresult->year);
            $after = '&nbsp;('.$arcresult->posts.')';
            echo '<a href="'.$url.'>'.$text.$after.'</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

This function should do what you want. Customize the markup in there the way you like

Comment: This looks right.  How would I call this in my sidebar.php?

Comment: put the function in functions.php & just make the call directly. or if you like, copy the function content to sidebar.php